# PATCH request not updating Webflow collection item fields correctly

Tags: node.js, json, http, webflow

I am trying to update a Webflow collection item using a PATCH request in Node.js.
I am computing the new values for the starrating, totalrating, and overallrating fields using the rating parameter passed in the request.
However, when I send the PATCH request to Webflow's API, the starrating and totalrating fields are not being updated correctly.
Specifically, the starrating field is always being set to 1, and the totalrating field is not being updated with the correct value.
I have verified that the computed values for newRatingTotal and newRatingCount are correct using console.log() statements in the code.
I have also checked the network request in the browser developer console and confirmed that the starrating and totalrating fields are being sent with the correct values.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

I tried updating a Webflow collection item using a PATCH request in Node.js. I computed the new values for the starrating, totalrating, and overallrating fields using the rating parameter passed in the request. I expected the starrating and totalrating fields to be updated correctly with the computed values. However, when I sent the PATCH request to Webflow's API, the starrating field was always set to 1, and the totalrating field was not being updated with the correct value. I have checked the network request in the browser developer console and confirmed that the starrating and totalrating fields are being sent with the correct values. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

```
const https = require('https');

const itemID = '12345'; // Replace with a valid item ID from your Webflow collection
const rating = '5'; // Replace with a rating value that you want to add to the item

const webflowAPIKey = 'YOUR_WEBFLOW_API_KEY'; // Replace with your Webflow API key

const getItemURL = `/collections/COLLECTION_ID/items/${itemID}`;
const getItemOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  hostname: 'api.webflow.com',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${webflowAPIKey}`,
  },
  path: getItemURL,
};

https.request(getItemOptions, (itemResponse) => {
  let itemData = '';

  itemResponse.on('data', (chunk) => {
    itemData += chunk;
  });

  itemResponse.on('end', () => {
    const getItemData = JSON.parse(itemData);
    console.log('Initial item data:', getItemData);

    const newRating = parseFloat(rating);
    const newRatingTotal = (parseFloat(getItemData.totalrating) || 0) + newRating;
    const newRatingCount = (parseFloat(getItemData.starrating) || 0) + 1;
    const overallRating = newRatingTotal / newRatingCount;

    console.log('Computed values:', {
      newRating,
      newRatingTotal,
      newRatingCount,
      overallRating,
    });

    const updateItemURL = `/collections/COLLECTION_ID/items/${itemID}`;
    const updateItemOptions = {
      method: 'PATCH',
      hostname: 'api.webflow.com',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${webflowAPIKey}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      path: updateItemURL,
    };

    const updateRequest = https.request(updateItemOptions, (updateResponse) => {
      let updateData = '';

      updateResponse.on('data', (chunk) => {
        updateData += chunk;
      });

      updateResponse.on('end', () => {
        const updateResult = JSON.parse(updateData);
        console.log('Updated item data:', updateResult);
      });
    });

    updateRequest.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });

    const data = JSON.stringify({
      fields: {
        starrating: newRatingCount,
        totalrating: newRatingTotal,
        overallrating: overallRating,
      },
    });

    console.log('PATCH request data:', data);

    updateRequest.write(data);
    updateRequest.end();
  });
}).end();
```